# Is there such thing called sum of absolute sum?

Tags: definition, sum

Sum of absolute difference (SAD) is common in image processing as a measure of similarity. Is there such thing called **sum of absolute sum** in image processing or other field? Does it have any significant meaning?

Comment: Where have you seen this term? Do you have any context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of looking at *difference*s is to see how different two things are (size of differences will tend to be larger when they're not the same than when they're identical apart from noise).

For example, if you want to see if Jon and Sansa have similar heights, knowing the sum of their heights is no use -- if their combined height is 34.5 hands you can't tell that from Khal Drogo and Daenerys's combined height of 34.5 hands.

[I have two pieces of string that when I add their lengths I get 50 cm. How close to the same length are they?]

It's the *difference* that tells you how *different* they are, which if you're trying to assess the extent of dissimilarity is what you need. So if Jon is 17 hands and Sansa is 17.5 hands high, that difference of just half a hand is what tells you their heights are pretty similar. The 3.5 hands difference between Daenerys and Khal Drogo tells you their heights are quite different - the best part of an ell. And Ser Gregor* and Tyrion's combined height of about 34.5 hands doesn't hint at the considerably larger difference.

Clearly their sums are pretty much of no value at all for telling you about similarity/dissimilarity (except as they might help you bound the absolute difference, since you know something about heights, like they must be positive, for example).

So the reason why sums aren't used and differences are is because only one of them actually measures the dissimilarity in a pair of values.

* (at least for season 1 Ser Gregor for which the combined height is about the same as the other pairs)

Comment: I understand and agree about the differences are used for measuring dissimilarity. Just wonder whether the opposite, which is "sum of sum", has any use in other area as I could not find any reference.

Comment: @askingtoomuch If you're no longer talking about measuring similarity it sounds like a very broad question indeed. While there's no obvious reason to take sums of absolute values of sums of pairs, without some restriction in context it would be similarly impossible to rule out. There might well be *dozens* of uses for it.